# Preserve space in value of a variable

Tags: bash

When using a sapce in a value of a variable, I always get this value somehow ugly expanded. The code looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

CURL="-H 'Accept: application/json' -s -S"

curl ${CURL} https://api.github.com/feeds
```

Executing this with `bash -x` results in:

```
+ CURL='-H '\''Accept: application/json'\'' -s -S'
+ curl -H ''\''Accept:' 'application/json'\''' -s -S https://api.github.com/feeds
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'
```

Btw I know that space is not necessary, this is just an example.
One solution to this problem is to encode the space to `\x20` as in

```sh
#!/bin/bash

CURL="-H Accept:\x20application/json"

curl ${CURL} https://api.github.com/feeds
```

This works

```
+ CURL='-H Accept:\x20application/json'
+ curl -H 'Accept:\x20application/json' https://api.github.com/feeds
```

but I find this solution is not good readable.

Is there an other way of quoting the space in the value of the variable, so the space remains preserved and the string (value) is good readable?

Comment: `curl "$CURL" https://...`?

Comment: @L3viathan No, that passes a single argument `-H 'Accept ...` rather than two separate options `-H` and `Accept...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what arrays are for: storing sequences of values that can't easily be embedded or extracted from a single string.

```
curl_opts=(-H "Accept: application/json")

curl "${curl_opts[@]}" https:/api.github.com/feeds
```